# Now i am using node latest version (17.4.0) "npm install node sass" command while using to react it these error produced. how to be resolved?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

[image]

Now i am using node  latest version (17.4.0) and current version(16.13.1)" npm install node sass" command while using to react  it  these error produced.  how to be resolved ?

Comment: What version of `npm`? Also, it looks like you're on windows, is that correct? Have you tried updating tar?

Comment: Literally, i used these two version but did not get it. so finally i used to node version(17.4.0) Didn't take that either.

Comment: Please post the full verbatim error message as text. I guess the problem is related to Python. You can see it in the last line of your screenshot.

Comment: I agree with @jabaa. It looks like python is misconfigured according to the error

Answer (score -1):

you need the lastest version of tar to do that you need to run this command

> npm i -g tar@latest

Comment: sorry,  it did not working that i have already used  in latest version "tar": "^6.1.11", then how to get it

Comment: What's the message says?

Comment: npm install tar@6 -g

Comment: tar was successfully installed and then i will using npm start command now these Error was showing. Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: Windows 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (93)

Comment: sorry for late reply first you need is to rebuild node-sass

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to install `sass`? You should do `npm install sass`